# What are "industrial chops"?

Tags: expressions

I've seen the expression *industrial chops* in a few texts, but looking at them all, and seeing the definition of *chop* in a dictionary did not provide me a clear meaning.

> In this way, 3D printing is more in line with with Kickstarter and Etsy, where people are delving into product development in ways that previously required storefronts, ***industrial chops*** and sizeable investments. (from http://airshipdaily.com/blog/3d-printing-separating-science-fiction-from-reality)
>
> The Aussie software supremo challenged the Tesla and Space X founder to help out, and prove the ***industrial chops*** of his batteries in the process. (from https://www.nbr.co.nz/article/tesla-wins-contract-stabilise-south-australia%E2%80%99s-power-system-world%E2%80%99s-largest-battery-ck)
>
> The inefficiencies at the plants are immediately familiar to anyone with experience of modern corporate Australia, despite their probable lack of Ireland-esque ***industrial chops***. (from http://peteg.org/blog/noise/books/2016-06-30-DavidIreland-TheUnknownIndustrialPrisoner.autumn)

They seem a sort of non-American slang or jargon, but I cannot infer the precise meaning of *chop* in this case.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chop), chop as a noun:

> Definition of chop (Entry 2 of 4)
>
> 1a : a forceful usually slanting blow with or as if with an ax or cleaver
>
> b : a sharp downward blow or stroke
>
> 2 : a small cut of meat often including part of a rib
>
> 3 : a mark made by or as if by chopping
>
> 4 : material that has been chopped up
>
> 5a : a short abrupt motion (as of a wave)
>
> 5b : a stretch of choppy sea
>
> 6 : chopper sense 6 (a high-bouncing batted baseball)
>
> 7 chiefly British : abrupt elimination or removal (as from a job)
>
> *it is the very top men who have got the chop — Daily Mirror*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I looked up plural **[chops](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chops)** in Wiktionary: "One's skill at any endeavor; ability, talent; competency."

Hence, "industrial chops" = "industrial skills", "industrial competency".

Sometimes you've got to investigate plural meanings - there can be additional meanings for the plural form of a word.

Comment: A kudo to you for bringing up the fact that trying to look up a word after taking the -s off the end may not work.

Comment: The plural thing is an excellent point. Yes, ***kudos*** to you.

Comment: "Chop" is something you can do to an onion.  "Chops" is the skill to *chop* onions quickly.

Comment: For interest: The meaning of "chops" for "skills", is from the meaning of chops as in your mouth/jaw. In 1940s Jazz; players who could use their mouth well, were said to have "[good] chops" (or similar) - and the slang for *chops* meaning *skills* developed.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. A fairly common use is to refer to "Acting Chops". For example: "It's a tough role, but I think Mr Cumberbatch has the acting chops to pull it off!"

Comment: Merriam-Webster also has this definition under the plural: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chops , upvoted

Comment: @Acccumulation i see what you did there

Comment: It's journalist-speak to use "chops" in this weirdly extended sense.  A magician can have chops, yes; I guess you can extend it to other performing arts like acting; but "industrial chops" is something no industrialist or engineer would say, and no layman either.  You can see other examples of journalese, like "supremo", or the contorted formation "Ireland-esque" (referring to a person, not the country).

Answer (score 2):

@CowperKettle's answer already tackles the question just fine, but since you used Merriam-Webster in the question I want to add an answer from that source.

You looked up [chop](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chop) on Merriam-Webster, but they also have a separate entry for [chops](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chops):

> Definition of chops
>
> 1. JAW
> 2. a. MOUTH
>      b. the fleshy covering of the jaws
>      // a dog licking its chops
> 3. EMBOUCHURE
>      *broadly* : the technical facility of a musical performer
> 4. **expertise in a particular field or activity**
>      // acting chops

(Emphasis mine)

Your examples all use the 4th definition above. As @CowperKettle pointed out, this is a case where the plural version of a noun (*chops*) takes on extra meanings besides just "more than one of that noun (*chop*)".